# Implementing the Bresenham Algorithm

Tags: haskell

Hi I'm trying to write some basic code to implement the Bresenham Algorithm but I'm stuck trying to use `round` and `/`. My code is:

```
bresenhamAlgorithm :: Coord -> Coord -> Int -> Int
bresenhamAlgorithm (x1, y1) (x2, y2) x'= round $ (fromIntegral ((y2 - 
y1) * (x' - x1)) / fromIntegral (x2 - x1)) + y1
```

I keep getting the `No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of ‘/’` and `No instance for (RealFrac Int) arising from a use of ‘round’` errors occuring. I don't understand as I believed that fromIntegral would convert the numerator and denominator to fractionals which would allow for the use of the `/` operation?

Comment: You didn't convert the other addend (`y1`).

Comment: you can structure it as `( round $ ... ) + y1` and it might work (depending on the definition of `Coord`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't understand as I believed that fromIntegral would convert the numerator and denominator to fractionals which would allow for the use of the / operation?

Yes, your understanding is basically correct but you made a small oversight.

---

Here is your code formatted slightly differently:

```
bresenhamAlgorithm :: Coord -> Coord -> Int -> Int
bresenhamAlgorithm (x1, y1) (x2, y2) x'= round $
  (
    fromIntegral ((y2 - y1) * (x' - x1)) 
  / fromIntegral (x2 - x1)
  ) + y1
```

this is (because `+` binds stronger than `$`) equivalent to:

```
bresenhamAlgorithm :: Coord -> Coord -> Int -> Int
bresenhamAlgorithm (x1, y1) (x2, y2) x'= round (
  (
    fromIntegral ((y2 - y1) * (x' - x1)) 
  / fromIntegral (x2 - x1)
  ) + y1)
```

The problem here is actually neither `round` nor `/`, it's your `+ y1` at the end. Because `y1` is already known to be `Int`, the type checker tries to unify

```
fromIntegral ((y2 - y1) * (x' - x1)) / fromIntegral (x2 - x1)
```

with `Int`, which of course fails because `/` isn't allowed with `Int`.

The solution is to add *another* `fromIntegral`:

```
bresenhamAlgorithm :: Coord -> Coord -> Int -> Int
bresenhamAlgorithm (x1, y1) (x2, y2) x'= round $
  (
    fromIntegral ((y2 - y1) * (x' - x1)) 
  / fromIntegral (x2 - x1)
  ) + fromIntegral y1 -- we need y1 as a fractional
```

Alternatively you could also wrap the everything before `+ y1` - including the `round` - in parentheses, that would work too.

---

Now the reason this wasn't caught earlier is because `fromIntegral` can actually convert integer types to *any* number type... including themselves. So in this case, because of how the expression was written the typechecker inferred that you meant `fromIntegral` to convert `Int` to... `Int` again. Which is not what you meant, but the compiler doesn't know that.

If we add a small helper function:

```
toDouble :: Int -> Double
toDouble = fromIntegral
```

and use it in your definition instead of `fromIntegral`

```
bresenhamAlgorithm :: Coord -> Coord -> Int -> Int
bresenhamAlgorithm (x1, y1) (x2, y2) x'= round $
  (
    toDouble ((y2 - y1) * (x' - x1)) 
  / toDouble (x2 - x1)
  ) + y1
```

to force the conversion, we actually get a more helpful error message:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Double’ with actual type ‘Int’
• In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘y1’
  In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
    ‘(toDouble ((y2 - y1) * (x' - x1)) / toDouble (x2 - x1)) + y1’
  In the expression:
    round
      $ (toDouble ((y2 - y1) * (x' - x1)) / toDouble (x2 - x1)) + y1

    ) + y1
        ^^
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help! I now understand why the use of the `+` operation would break the algorithm, but I tried to implement your suggestions resulting in this code:

    bresenhamAlgorithm :: Coord -> Coord -> Int -> Int
    bresenhamAlgorithm (x1, y1) (x2, y2) x'= round $ fromIntegral ((y2 
    - y1) * (x' - x1)) / fromIntegral (x2 - x1))+ fromIntegral y1

But it now gives me an error on the round operation `Defaulting the following constraints to type 'Double'`. How do I keep it as an Int?

Comment: @spicyboi `Double` is good, you *want* to divide the `Double`s, for better precision.

Comment: @spicyboi That's not an error, it's just a warning telling you that because you didn't really tell the compiler what type `fromIntegral` should return it just picked one for you (`Double`). If you use the `toDouble` function from this answer instead (which just restricts `fromIntegral`), the message will go away (think of it as a "yes, that's what I meant" you can tell the compiler).